# Login to wordpress by clicking a link and specifying usernaname and password in url

Tags: php, login, forms, html, authentication

I'm running a php application on an ubuntu server that's completely independent of my wordpress site. I'm using an iFrame of the server inside the wordpress site, but I need to login to Wordpress with it (because I need to pass `$token` and `$videoid`).

On the Ubuntu server, I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form target="_top" action="http://website.com/login/?token=<?=$token?>&videoid=<?=$videoid?>" method="post">
<p>
<input placeholder="Email Address..." type="text" name="email" id="email"><br><br>
<input placeholder="Password..." type="password" name="password" id="password"><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="document.getElementById('create').style.display='none';">
</form>
```

I'm successfully passing the username, password, token and videoid to a login page on the wordpress site, but the best I've been able to do on that page is create a new form with those values. Is there any way I can auto-login on that page using the credentials passed from the form on the other server?

Comment: You could use the [wp_signon()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function